# Separate logging using LOG4J2

Tags: log4j2

I have a requirement to maintain separate logging files EAR1.log and EAR2.log for 2 Java EE applications EAR1 and EAR2 respectively using LOG4J2 v2.1.  Going through the internet, I could see help specific to LOG4J v1.x, but couldn’t find any for LOG4J2.

**EAR1 (need to use “EAR1-log4j2.xml”):**

```
1.  Web project  “web1”
2.  EJB project “ejb1”
3.  Java project “java1”
4.  Java project “java2”
5.  Java project “java3”
```

**EAR2 (need to use “EAR2-log4j2.xml”):**

```
1.  Web project  “web2”
2.  EJB project “ejb2”
3.  Java project “java1” (same as above)
4.  Java project “java2” (same as above)
5.  Java project “java3” (same as above)
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html

what is working now:
my log4j2.xml is placed in ApplicationServer classpath & a single log is successfully getting written for both the EAR’s

my completed attempts to maintain separate log files for both EAR’s:
•   Modifying web.xml only applies the logging change to the web project alone
•   I tried the following code, but this applies only to current class

```
LoggerContext loggerCtx = Configurator.initialize("mrpst", null, PathOfMyLog4j2XmlPath );
                  Logger log = loggerCtx.getLogger("MyClassName");
```

I’m trying to check if it is possible to complete this requirement by editing log4j2.xml alone(without code change). Appreciate if a documentation link can be provided or any alternate approach.

Comment: What application server are you using? ie Websphere, JBoss, Weblogic, Glassfish.

Comment: @Paul, we are using Websphere Application server 8.0.0.8. Dependant jars used are log4j-api/core/web version 2.1

Comment: If the EARs packages have a key difference, you can create two Appenders and two Loggers, for each package structure.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to inject context into your log event and filter on that context using a logger route, which directs to an appropriate appender.

At the point of logging:

```
String routeKey = SOME_FIELD_THAT_IDENTIFIES_CONTAINER;
ThreadContext.put( "myEARroute", routeKey );
```

In your log4j2.xml config:

```
<Routing name="myEARroute">
    <Routes pattern="$${ctx:myEARroute}">
        <!-- if you forget to inject context, the routing key will be empty -->
        <Route
            key="$${ctx:myEARroute}"
            ref="STDOUT" />
        <Route
            key="EAR1"
            ref="myEAR1Appender" />
        <Route
            key="EAR2"
            ref="myEAR2Appender" />
    </Routes>
</Routing>
```

Now you just have to create appenders matching your appender names:

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile
    name="myEAR1Appender"
    filename="logs/Ear1.log"
    <!-- fill in the rest of your appender config, as desired -->
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

repeat for other appenders.

Comment: Since I have no other way to contact you, I have to comment on this answer. If you make a mistake in your vote or have something to add, you can leave a comment under my post instead of editing the post. Edits which changes the meaning of the post won't make past the review, so do them when you reach 2k and when you are completely sure. As for the content of your suggested edit, just leave a message in RegEx room or a comment under my post and let's discuss it there.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Obviously still new to the rules. :)  As way of explanation for the erroneous click on your answer, FF went all black and I was randomly clicking to try and get my video driver to re-render.  Had no idea what tab was active and when FF crashed and restarted, I saw that I down-voted. D'OH!